# How can I use a third party api in the vendors directory of symfony from my controller

Tags: php, symfony, structure, vendor

I am working with an existing controller in symfony and need to use an api that I have in my vendors directory. Needless to say I am entering a pre-existent, large scale project and with minimum experience in symfony I am not too sure of how to use the vendor directory. When I have tried using "use vendor\fullcontact\sdk*********;" symfony tells me that there is no class called this in my bundle. I have looked for information on using the vendor directory but have came up dry. Any information regarding how I can start using my vendor directory would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are using the [PHP Library](https://github.com/fullcontact/fullcontact-api-php) for FullContact API.

This library don't use namespace so you can simply try to use it adding an initial slash to the class when you are using it. As Example:

```
$this->name = new \Services_FullContact_Name($apikey);
```

Hope this help

Comment: Wow this did the trick! I'm not too familiar with whatever method the api was made global with or the backslash method of referring to it but it's working great!

Comment: hi @colinrickels, The \ is used in PHP 5.3 for namespaces. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php for more information on namespaces and PHP.

Comment: Hi @colinrickels if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.